# Как пишется "неподавшие документы лица"?

Tags: орфография

"Неподавшие" пишется слитно или раздельно?
Предложение:
Сделать что-то с лицами, неподавшими документы на оформление пропуска"

Comment: To me it seems a participle, and hence it should be separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write it separately: *не подавшими*

Rosenthal, 70.2:

> Пишется раздельно *не* с причастиями, имеющими при себе пояснительные слова, например: *не возвращенная автору рукопись, не замеченные корректором опечатки, не сданные в срок гранки, не изданные при жизни писателя варианты отдельных глав романа*.
>
> Примечание 1. Данное правило распространяется и на те случаи, когда причастие с пояснительными словами образует часть составного сказуемого, например: *Многие письма писателя остались не опубликованными при его жизни; Бездарность сойдет со сцены не замеченной в искусстве*. Ср. в другой синтаксической конструкции: *Трудно представить себе его не участвующим активно в общественной жизни.*

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Я правильно понял, что здесь поясняющее или зависимое слово - это "документы"? Просто не уверен насчет этого. Вот, например, "лица, не подавшие вовремя документы, будут наказаны". Здесь точно поясняющее или зависимое слово "вовремя". Вот из вашего ответа пример: "неизданные варианты отдельных глав" - вот в таком варианте уже пишется слитно?

Comment: @Zeolite: updated my answer. Honestly, Rosenthal goes into too much detail here, any participial (as opposed to adjectival) clause requires separate usage of *не*.

Comment: Большое спасибо!